# How can I move the Microsoft Word Styles Pane when the top is off the screen?

Tags: microsoft-word, window

The Microsoft Word Styles Pane is opening with the top 20% off the top of the screen.  How can I move it?

Normal windows can be moved via the keyboard using the alt-space shortcut, but that doesn't work on tool windows.  The only instructions I found for docking it involve dragging it which I can't do either.

Comment: Try changing the screen resolution; might pop it back inside.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks!  I didn't try that because docking and undocking my laptop changed the resolution too, but that didn't fix the problem.  But explicitly changing it did.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Changing the screen resolution is the usual method of pushing windows back inside the screen borders when anything like this happens.